# Weighted mean, sd and median - Size Weighted (Negative Numbers)

Tags: excel, statistics, portfolio, weighted-average

I need to calculate the weighted median, average, sd of PE funds' returns. I weighted the sample according to the amount of committed capital of a fund, but I should consider negative products to analyze underperforming funds. However, I'm not sure if I can use neg/zero values to derivate these statistic measures.

Wμ = Σ(w,x)/Σw --> the formula i consider for wgt. average

w = Fund's size
x = net IRR

(w,x) = Neg & Pos values.

How can I calculate those measures, including negative/zero values? I'm doing it in Excel

My standpoint is the Kaplan and Schoar's approach (Private Equity Performance: Returns, Persistence, and Capital Flows)

Any help on this matter is really appreciated!